# FromKnownColor argument interpretation

Tags: vb.net

```
Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor("Control")
```

What does this mean? What is "Control" here?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider looking into [FromKnownColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromknowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx). It's useful if you want to parse a string to a colour. Which is exactly what the colour `Control` is. The result is also the equivalent to `SystemColors.Control`.

Look into [SystemColors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors(v=vs.110).aspx) - the Visual Studio IDE integrates a whole lot of colours into one list - and obviously not of the same type (`Color` / `SystemColors`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is that this does not compile with **[Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) On**:

```
Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor("Control")
```

Instead it produces the following compile error:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'System.Drawing.KnownColor'.

Change the code to:

```
Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control)
```

Back to your question *What is "Control" here?* and extending on from [Alex M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7562101/alex-m)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42717559/6375113).  "Control" is the name of a colour. You can see this in the designer which may help you to understand:

[image]